# Get phone number by contact name

Tags: android

I’m trying to get phone number from contacts by providing the phone number. what I've done so far:

```
public static String getPhone(Context context, String displayName) {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" LIKE '%" + displayName + "&'";
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}, selection, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String contactName = null;
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        }

        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        //Log.d("Contact",contactName.toString());
        return contactName;
    }
```

Comment: And what's not working/not as you expect? What's the problem you're asking for help with?

Comment: `get phone number (...) by providing the phone number`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code out. You will need to set the permission in the manifest "android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" on true.

```
public String getPhoneNumber(String name, Context context) {
    String ret = null;
    String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" like'%" + name +"%'";
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            projection, selection, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        ret = c.getString(0);
    }
    c.close();
    if(ret==null)
        ret = "Unsaved";
    return ret;
    }
```

UPDATE:

This code snippet will allow you to read all messages from a particular contact:

```
StringBuilder smsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       final String SMS_URI_INBOX = "content://sms/inbox"; 
        final String SMS_URI_ALL = "content://sms/";  
        try {  
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(SMS_URI_INBOX);  
            String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "address", "person", "body", "date", "type" };  
            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, "address='123456789'", null, "date desc");
             if (cur.moveToFirst()) {  
                int index_Address = cur.getColumnIndex("address");  
                int index_Person = cur.getColumnIndex("person");  
                int index_Body = cur.getColumnIndex("body");  
                int index_Date = cur.getColumnIndex("date");  
                int index_Type = cur.getColumnIndex("type");         
                do {  
                    String strAddress = cur.getString(index_Address);  
                    int intPerson = cur.getInt(index_Person);  
                    String strbody = cur.getString(index_Body);  
                    long longDate = cur.getLong(index_Date);  
                    int int_Type = cur.getInt(index_Type);  

                    smsBuilder.append("[ ");  
                    smsBuilder.append(strAddress + ", ");  
                    smsBuilder.append(intPerson + ", ");  
                    smsBuilder.append(strbody + ", ");  
                    smsBuilder.append(longDate + ", ");  
                    smsBuilder.append(int_Type);  
                    smsBuilder.append(" ]\n\n");  
                } while (cur.moveToNext());  

                if (!cur.isClosed()) {  
                    cur.close();  
                    cur = null;  
                }  
            } else {  
                smsBuilder.append("no result!");  
            } // end if  
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException ex) {  
            Log.d("SQLiteException", ex.getMessage());  
        }
```

Comment: That works but when i apply the number buck to sms inbox to get messages from the current number it returns nothing...